# Detecting Hough Lines that are the farthest from each other?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform, houghlines

I am working on detecting a sheet from an image. Currently, detecting its edges and drawing Hough lines is very successful. But, for the sake of generalization and expanding, I need to set the threshold low, which results in a lot of unnecessary lines. As you can see below:

[image]

My goal would be to find only the lines that are the farthest away from each other, both vertically and horizontally. The result should look something like this:

[image]

Thank You for Your help!

Comment: you can loop through your lines and find the ones which are maximally apart in either direction, it is not the most intelligent way but it works. for the horizontal you compare x values, for the vertical compare y values. another approach would be to do some color thresholding to mask off the not white table

Comment: Seems like bimodal thresholding will  work  in  your  case.  Convert to HSV and threshold  using H or S